# How to parsing Velocity Variables using ANTLR4

Tags: parsing, antlr4, velocity

The variables of Velocity has following notation. (see [Velocity User Guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/user-guide.html#variables)):

> The shorthand notation of a variable consists of a leading "$" character followed by a VTL Identifier. A VTL Identifier must start with an alphabetic character (a .. z or A .. Z). The rest of the characters are limited to the following types of characters:
>
> - alphabetic (a .. z, A .. Z)
> - numeric (0 .. 9)
> - underscore ("_")

I want to use lexer mode to split the normal text and the variables, so I wrote something like this:

```
// default mode
DOLLAR : ‘$’ -> pushMode(VARIABLE);
TEXT : ~[$]+? -> skip;

mode VARIABLE:
ID : [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9-_]*;
???? : XXX -> popMode;   // how can I pop mode to default?
```

Because the notation of the variables has no explicit end character, so I don't know how to determine its end.

Maybe I got it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would pop out of that scope like this:

```antlr
mode VARIABLE;
  ID  : [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9-_]* -> popMode;
```

Here's a quick demo:

```antlr
lexer grammar VelocityLexer;

DOLLAR : '$' -> more, pushMode(VARIABLE);
TEXT   : ~[$]+ -> skip;

mode VARIABLE;
  // the `-` needs to be escaped!
  ID : [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9\-_]* -> popMode;
```

Note the `more` in the `DOLLAR` which will cause the `$` to be included in the `ID` token. If you don't, you end up with two tokens (`$` and `foo` for the input `$foo`)

Test the grammar with the following Java class:

```java
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    VelocityLexer lexer = new VelocityLexer(CharStreams.fromString("<strong>$Mu</strong>$foo..."));
    CommonTokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    tokenStream.fill();

    for (Token t : tokenStream.getTokens()) {
      System.out.printf("%-10s '%s'\n", VelocityLexer.VOCABULARY.getSymbolicName(t.getType()), t.getText());
    }
  }
}
```

which will print:

```
ID         '$Mu'
ID         '$foo'
EOF        '<EOF>'
```

However, I think a lexical mode is not a good choice in case of an `ID`. Why not simply do:

```antlr
lexer grammar VelocityLexer;

DOLLAR : '$' [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*;
TEXT   : ~[$]+ -> skip;
```

?

Comment: Two minor points. First, slightly cleaner to use `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]`. Placing the `-` last in a set excludes interpretation as a set range operator.  Second, place the `popMode` on the `ID` rule: the variable name is fully matched (and emitted) prior to any mode pop. Benefit is that it precludes having to consider whether the character matched by the `POP` rule is significant.

Comment: @GRosenberg I've mixed feelings about not escaping the `-` and placing it at the end or start of the set: the OP might append character after it again. Good point about nr. 2: I was already focussed on not using modes! :) I'll edit, thanks.

Comment: @bartkeirs fully relate to the mixed feelings; similar problem if the OP later adds something between the escape and hyphen.